# visited image link pseudo class does not work in Chrome

Tags: html, css

I've encountered a weird behaviour in chrome. a:visited overrides a:visited img and I have no idea why. I've checked in developer tools and it states clearly that it's the a:visited and not any other style or classes. I wonder what's causing this behaviour for me in chrome. Here is my css for the links and image links:

```
a {
    color:#046DAD;
    text-decoration:none;
}

a:visited {
    color:#304198;
}

a:hover {
    color:#39F;
    text-decoration:underline;
}

a:active {
    color:#ecc31b;
}

a img {
    border:1px solid #c1c1c1;
}

a:visited img {
    border:0px solid #c1c1c1;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#c1c1c1;
}

a:hover img {
    border:1px solid #39f;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#39f;
}

a:active img {
    border:1px solid #fbcb09; 
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#fbcb09;
}
```

The HTML structure:

```
<div class="content">       
<a href="x.html"><img src="x.jpg" alt=""/></a>
</div>
```

The a:visited color still overrides it if I change it to

```
.content a img {
    border:1px solid #c1c1c1;
}

.content a:visited img {
    border:0px solid #c1c1c1;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#c1c1c1;
}

.content a:hover img {
    border:1px solid #39f;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#39f;
}

.content a:active img {
    border:1px solid #fbcb09; 
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#fbcb09;
}
```

Have you guys encountered anything similar?

Edit:

```
<div class="content">       
    <a href="x.html" class="contentimage"><img src="x.jpg" alt=""/></a>
</div>

a:visited.contentimage {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#c1c1c1;
}
```

So I tried using the code above as a workaround to override the style of each image link. That's the only way I solved it. Any ideas on easier workarounds?

Comment: Are you sure this only happens in Chrome? The rule `a.visited img` targets the `img` element, not the `a` element, so it shouldn't override the `a.visited` rule

Comment: Yup, it only happens in Chrome. In Firefox and IE it works fine, visited image link will just have the #c1c1c1 grey border instead of the #ecc31b purple border. Only thing missing in IE is that the active pseudo class doesn't work.

Comment: Where are you even getting #ecc31b? I see that for `:active` but that shouldn't affect `:visited` at all

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS pseudo class combinations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000940/css-pseudo-class-combinations)

Answer (score 0):

maybe try a img:visited? Not sure if :visited works same way as :hover, but i guess yes, so it should work

Answer (score 0):

There is a security concern that [by styling `a:visited` a malicious website can find out where you've been](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8001629). Right now the only style rule WebKit allows for `:visited` links is `color`.