# CSS pseudo class combinations

Tags: css, css-selectors

How can I style a anchor tag so that once the link is visited it will change to Red and append [Old] to the end of the link.

So how do I combine these two:

```
a:visited{
   color:Red
}
a:after{
   content:[Old]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a privacy issue. As browser can detect element styles, it can therefore know what sites did you visit. An right now JS can detect it for a very large number of links in very short time. So for security reasons modern browser's ability to detect :visited class is severely cutted down.

Read more about it on mozilla's blog: http://blog.mozilla.com/security/2010/03/31/plugging-the-css-history-leak/

Citation from Webkit changelog:

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4196

> Impact: A maliciously crafted website may be able to determine which
>   sites a user has visited
>
> Description: A design issue exists in WebKit's handling of the CSS
>   :visited pseudo-class. A maliciously crafted website may be able to
>   determine which sites a user has visited. This update limits the
>   ability of web pages to style pages based on whether links are
>   visited.

Similiar questions (have more links):

- [Google chrome a:visited background image not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788855/google-chrome-avisited-background-image-not-working/3842816#3842816)
- [How can I remove the underline of a link in chrome using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909887/how-can-i-remove-the-underline-of-a-link-in-chrome-using-css/4910041#4910041)

Comment: Thank you! I found similar articles that mention this. I am just going to use JavaScript for now.